# A light(er)weight twitter feed widget?

Tags: twitter, load-time, widgets

I'm using the "official" twitter feed widget, and I just noticed in Firefox's network inspector that it's adding +- 220 kB of data to my site at load time.
100 kB is the "widgets.js" file, the other 100 kB is a json file (which weirdly enough is only 9kB when I copy the URL and download it from the address bar??).

Any suggestion for reducing those file sizes? Apart from custom coding a RSS feed extractor thingy which wouldn't depend on their widgets.js?

I'm just trying to skim some fat for faster load times :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I was coding something to deal with the problem, I'd have the feed download using PHP every so often (maybe via cron job) to a temp folder on the site in json. Then instead of polling twitter, I could serve up my own slimmed down pre-formatted version without the overhead. Simples :)

Steve